# How to mention specific length (either 5 or 10) for an HTML input in HTML5

Tags: html

I am working with MVC application containing views developed using HTML5 `input` types.
I have a ZIP code field for which the validation should be either 5 or 10 characters, the user should be able to enter either 5 or 10 if the user enters below 5 or more than 5 below 10 should not be accepted.

He should enter either 5 or 10 characters.
Below is the example pattern.

> the format will be `99999[-9999]` for example, `15220` or `15220-4056`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `data-val-regex-pattern` and `data-val-regex` attributes for validating the regular expression.
The code will be like:

`<input type="text" data-val-regex-pattern="[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" data-val-regex="ZIP code, must match either 'XXXXX' or 'XXXXX-XXXX'">`

Here are a list of html5 input types for specific validations [List of Html5 specific validations used for unobtrusive client side validations](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pattern` attribute and a regex for validation. 
You can validate the format even better:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" title="ZIP code, must match either 'XXXXX' or 'XXXXX-XXXX'">
```

Details on the `pattern` attribute: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Browser support: see https://caniuse.com/#search=pattern

---

Regex `[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?` explanation:

- `[0-9]{5}` matches 5 digits
- `(-[0-9]{4})?` matches either an empty string or '-XXXX'.

---

Please note that you can't rely solely on Client-side validation. Client-side validation improves user experience, but it can be easily manipulated and doesn't protect you from malicious requests. Server-side validation is required.

Comment: Since this is pure html solution I'd also mention that it is manipulable by the client. So a backend validation is still needed

Comment: @Alex, I am not sure what exactly the issue is but the solution is not working for me..

Comment: I tested in both mozilla and chrome

Comment: @Meena, the HTML5 validation is triggered upon form submission, when the `<input type="submit">` is clicked. Is this the case in your project?

Comment: Or you can call `checkValidity()` method on the form.

Comment: You can read more about HTML5 constraint validations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation